# SQL in CartoDB to select using OR more efficiently

Tags: sql, carto, filter

I made this map a CartoDB map to to show the countries that have banned their citizens working as maids in the Gulf states, I also want to show the Gulf states as one colour.

I created this SQL query for the world borders layer, the one you make available for use to all CartoDB users, in my map:

SELECT * FROM world_borders where name in ('Nepal', 'Kenya','Syrian Arab Republic','Pakistan','Bangladesh')

However, whenever I exit the map to the dashboard and then enter it again for editing, it defaults back to this query:

SELECT * FROM world_borders WHERE name ILIKE '%syria%'

This is a query which came from a filter I had applied in the past. Is the filter over riding the query somehow? I checked to make sure the filter was cleared. I have a free account. SQL queries seem to still be allowed for this level of account. What am I doing wrong? Additionally, how do I add/delete fields from the world borders table I've imported into my map?

Wil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear the querys, you need to click on the option "**clear view**"  in the green bar that appears in the data view: See image attachment:

[image]

About your second question (adding/deleting fields from tables), you need to click on the option "**Add column**". It is at the right menu (in Data View), the last option. I attach an image too:
[image: Adding columns]

Comment: http://ndthl.cartodb.com/viz/e09e337a-7f90-11e4-9dfa-0e9d821ea90d/public_map

Comment: Great and interesting map! ^^